# Automatic Refrence Counting (ARC) on iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, automatic-ref-counting

In iOS5 sdk, Compiler will take care of memory management (ARC). Suppose I had built my app using iOS 4.2 and had manually done all the releses. Now, If I am going to run that app on iOS 5, will compiler again try to insert its own memory management? In this case, won't it get crashed?

Comment: Have you tried to run it in iOS 5.0? what happened then?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I had written the code on xcode3.2.5/iOS4.2 and then, I tried running it using xcode4/iOS5.0 and it got crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start new project using iOS 5.0 SDK, you now have an option to turn on/off ARC..If you are running an existing project which is designed using pre iOS 5.0 version, ARC automatically is disabled..See apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) on transition to ARC

Answer (score 3):

No. You have to decide to use ARC. (Edit>Refactor>Convert to ARC). If you are not using ARC the compiler won't insert memory management code.